# Using which() over matrix row-wise without for loop

Tags: r

I have a matrix that looks like this

```
> a <- matrix(c(1,1,1,2,3,2,2,4,4,5,3,3,8,4,3,8),4,4, byrow = TRUE)
> a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    1    1    2
[2,]    3    2    2    4
[3,]    4    5    3    3
[4,]    8    4    3    8
```

Now I want to have a list of the indices for the minimum of each row. One way to do this is with a $\verb|for|$ loop

```
> b <- apply(a,1,min)
> c <- rep(list(), 4)
> for (i in 1:4){
    c[[i]] <- which(a[i,]==b[i])
  }
> c
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 3 4

[[4]]
[1] 3
```

I can't use $\verb|apply()|$ because the thing to repeat is a logical expression. Is there a way to do this without $\verb|for|$ loop?

Comment: This is an R programming question and if so it is off-topic here. See http://stackoverflow.com/. However, can't you define function which does the part "c[[i]] <- which(a[i,]==b[i])" and then feed it to apply?

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know we could use apply() this way.

I will post on stackoverflow from now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `apply`:

```
a <- matrix(c(1,1,1,2,3,2,2,4,4,5,3,3,8,4,3,8),4,4, byrow = TRUE)

> apply(a, 1, function(x) which(x == min(x)))
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 2 3

[[3]]
[1] 3 4

[[4]]
[1] 3
```